# How can I add Ractive instances to a list? in a parent Ractive instance?

Tags: mvp, ractivejs

I already have a Ractive [instance](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/new-ractive) (or [component](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/components) - it could be either) and I want to add it to a list in another Ractive instance.  Something like this:

```
var ListItemOne = new Ractive({
  data: { key: "hello" }
});

var ListItemTwo = new Ractive({
  data: { key: "world" }
});

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: "#output",
  template: "#template",
  data: { greeting: 'hi', name: 'there',
      listItems: [
        ListItemOne,
        ListItemTwo
      ]
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<p>{{greeting}} {{name}}!</p>

<ul>
  {{#listItems}}
  <li>{{key}}</li>
  {{/listItems}}
</ul>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mucosutete/1/edit?html,js,output)

Or using a method:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: "#output",
  template: "#template",
  data: {
    greeting: 'hi', name: 'there',
    listItems: []
   },

  addListItem: function(listItem){
    this.get('listItems').push(listItem);
  }
});

ractive.addListItem(ListItemOne);
ractive.addListItem(ListItemTwo);
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gisamewuye/1/edit?html,js,output)

Is it possible to use Ractive in this way?

---

Please note that I do not want this:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: "#output",
  template: "#template",
  data: { greeting: 'hi', name: 'there',
      listItems: [
        { key: "hello" },
        { key: "world" }
      ]
    }
});
```

As I already have the Ractive instances/components, and I am using MVP to define explicitly define the interface between application and view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in the list are ractive instances, so you have to call the get method to access their data if you want to use them that way (see http://jsbin.com/nomutofati/1/edit?html,js,output):

```
<ul>
  {{#listItems}}
  <li>{{this.get('key')}}</li>
  {{/listItems}}
</ul>
```

Comment: This gives me an idea. Is there a way to render them assuming they have a template? I tried {{this.render()}} but it returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am wondering if just maintain a pointer to the state in the Ractive "subinstance" is enough.  Then I would not need to pollute the template like this.

Comment: Is there a reason you're pre-instantiating the components? Normally you use the component tag in the parent template and ractive instantiates them for you.

Comment: > "I am wondering if just maintain a pointer to the state in the Ractive "subinstance" is enough" - so you're just trying to share data???

Comment: @martypdx good question.  I am experimenting with verbose presenters, and so rather than composing application state in composition layer and passing it as a massive JSON to the top Ractive instance, I am trying to be a lot more explicit about the possible data that can update, at the presenter level, [like this](http://goo.gl/iEmY76). To do this, I need to maintain a pointer to each "subview" in a list, and update it via a key, [like this](http://goo.gl/BKbCyW).

Comment: It seems like this approach does not rerender:  http://jsbin.com/bebeqegube/1/edit?html,js,output